# C# advice with list view

Tags: c#, filelist

I made a application were you enter persons information and you can save it in directory(C:\Inforation\example.txt).
Now i need to add new button and list view, but i dont know how to use list view.
I need to see all .txt files from directory in list view after pressing button.

Here's a part from code if it helps:

```
    {

        if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Informacija"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Informacija");

        MessageBox.Show("Save", "My notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("C:\\Informacija\\" + textBox1.Text + " " + textBox2.Text + ".txt"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Name: " + textBox1.Text);
            writer.WriteLine("Surname: " + textBox2.Text);
            writer.WriteLine("Birthday:" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
            writer.WriteLine("Person code:" + textBox4.Text + textBox3.Text);
            writer.WriteLine("Birth place:" + textBox5.Text);
            writer.WriteLine("Thelephone number: " + textBox6.Text);
            writer.WriteLine("Family status: " + comboBox2.Text);
            writer.WriteLine("E-mail:" + textBox8.Text + "@" + comboBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried and explain what is wrong in your works. Or do you expect a full functional code written for you?

Comment: Thats the problem... I have nothing to show, after fail i simply delete code that doenst work.

Answer (score 3):

Add a button and simply clear the lisview and then reload the files in that button.

Something like this...

```
        ListView1.Items.Clear();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(WHATEVERPATH);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {

            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
            item.Tag = file;

            ListView1.Items.Add(item);

        }
```

Comment: @user1448514, you may [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), Also just to get the text file, you may try `Directory.GetFiles(WHATEVERPATH,"*.txt");`